# Не срабатывает VK widget в Украине

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, виджет

Вот HTML

```
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
```

Вот подключение

```
VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 0, width: "auto", height: "auto", color1: 'FFFFFF', color2: '000', color3: '8b0202'}, 86930753);
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы если пользователь заходит из страны где запрещен VK ( к примеру Украина ) , то этот виджет не инициализировался и не блокировал из-за ошибки весь JS на сайте. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups"...);
} catch(error) {
  console.log("Error calling VK.Widgets.Group", error);
}
```

Comment: Через Яндекс Браузер в Украине всегда срабатывало, а так и в яндекс браузере не работает.